# How to join background image and gradient in Internet explorer

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, gradient

I am working on placing a gradient and a background image on an element using CSS. I started by going to Colorzilla for the gradient and it gave me this.

```
background: rgb(250,250,250);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(250,250,250,1) 0%, rgba(236,236,236,1) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(250,250,250,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(236,236,236,1)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(250,250,250,1) 0%,rgba(236,236,236,1) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(250,250,250,1) 0%,rgba(236,236,236,1) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(250,250,250,1) 0%,rgba(236,236,236,1) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(250,250,250,1) 0%,rgba(236,236,236,1) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fafafa', endColorstr='#ececec',GradientType=1 );
```

That works in all the major broswers including Internet Explorer (at least in IE9).

I then added the background images manually.

```
background: url('/public/src/images/features_arrow_fade.png') no-repeat 260px center, rgb(250,250,250);
background: url('/public/src/images/features_arrow_fade.png') no-repeat 260px center, -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(250,250,250,1) 0%, rgba(236,236,236,1) 100%);
background: url('/public/src/images/features_arrow_fade.png') no-repeat 260px center, -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(250,250,250,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(236,236,236,1)));
background: url('/public/src/images/features_arrow_fade.png') no-repeat 260px center, -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(250,250,250,1) 0%,rgba(236,236,236,1) 100%);
background: url('/public/src/images/features_arrow_fade.png') no-repeat 260px center, -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(250,250,250,1) 0%,rgba(236,236,236,1) 100%);
background: url('/public/src/images/features_arrow_fade.png') no-repeat 260px center, -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(250,250,250,1) 0%,rgba(236,236,236,1) 100%);
background: url('/public/src/images/features_arrow_fade.png') no-repeat 260px center, linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(250,250,250,1) 0%,rgba(236,236,236,1) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fafafa', endColorstr='#ececec',GradientType=0 );
```

This correctly displays the gradient with the image in all major browsers except IE. IE displays only the gradient. How can I get it to work in IE as well? I am willing to use jQuery if it will help!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create another element, It is impossible in =<IE9 to use multiple backgrounds